# Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm trying to get a random meal planner set up and am stuck on getting this error message, "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A" on this piece of code

```
=QUERY({Curries!A2:D;Soups!A2:D;Pasta!A2:D;Casseroles!A2:D},"Select A,C where C <= "& C4 &" Order by D desc Limit 5")
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can only use `A`, `B`, etc when you are directly referencing the ranges. `QUERY(Curries!A2:D, "select A,C where C <= "&C4&" order by D desc limit 5")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Col` references:

```
=QUERY({Curries!A2:D; Soups!A2:D; Pasta!A2:D; Casseroles!A2:D},
 "select Col1,Col3 where Col3 <= "&C4&" order by Col4 desc limit 5")
```

Comment: Is there a way to edit this to make it so the selected numbers are going to =14?

Comment: @Pikie you mean `"select Col1,Col2,Col3,...,Col14"` ?

Comment: No, the colums are giving me multiple numbers (servings of food per meal) that need to each be under or equal to 14, but is there a way to make it so the total servings is equal to 14?

Comment: @Pikie can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: Of course. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hvmHBB6R-jGVrbWMRLIihuMopAopaz14CUAhVkJ-R6A/edit?usp=sharing), so I'd like it to be so the total servings is always 14 when choosing randomly from the meal options